# plutil: command not found

Tags: bash, shell, fedora

Ultimate Goal:
I'm trying to convert a binary plist file to an xml format so that I can put it in an array and grab values from it. What I'm finding via web search on this is that the command for Linux comes from libplist.

Problem: I ran "yum install libplist" and it told me libplist is already installed and latest version. I've read that if I enter the following command:

```
plutil -i /mypath/file.plist > /mypath/file.xml.plist
```

That this will help accomplish my ultimate goal. However, when I do this only a blank file called file.xml.plist is created. Further, with this command and any other command involving plutil, I get a "bash: plutil: command not found. . ." error. Is libplist seemingly not installed (even though it says it is) or why would I repeatedly get this error? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Tried this in several variations and got no package available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `yum` to look for a package knowing the binary you want. For instance, if I want to install the package that provides `plutil`, I simply run this command:

```
$> yum provides plutil
```

Unfortunately, the result is `No matches found`... But you say you read that the `libplist` package provides this tool. Maybe it was renamed ? Let's use `repoquery` for this (if you don't have it, `yum provides repoquery` tells you that you need to install `yum-utils`).

```
$> repoquery --list libplist
/usr/bin/plistutil
/usr/lib/libplist++.so.3
/usr/lib/libplist++.so.3.0.0
/usr/lib/libplist.so.3
/usr/lib/libplist.so.3.0.0
/usr/share/doc/libplist
/usr/share/doc/libplist/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/libplist/COPYING.LESSER
/usr/share/doc/libplist/README
```

And what I see is that a program called `plistutil` was installed with this package !

I've never used `plutil`, so I can't tell you for sure `plistutil` is the program you want (but it probably is). What I wanted to do instead with this post is to show how you can use `yum` to install the packages you need !

Comment: Thanks! plistutil is indeed the command I need to be using. However when I convert it to an xml document the result is a messed up file, but at least I'm one step closer.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this thread while Googling for the same thing myself. After looking at a few solutions for my own company ([Screenplay](https://screenplay.dev/)) I decided to fork and iterate on a open-source, cross-platform, drop-in replacement for `plutil`:

https://github.com/screenplaydev/plutil

It's forked from Facebook's xcbuild (a tool developed by them to build xcode projects on Linux), but stripped down to just provide plist-editting functionality. That way you won't need to maintain separate code-paths for Mac and Linux environments.

Hope that's helpful!